# Do I need "will" in the following cases?

Tags: modal-verbs

> If you talk to me about cars or soccer, I (will)
> yawn until my jaw snaps, but if you get me started about the nature of
> the soul or conciousness, I can go on for hours.
>
> If you're obsessed with a
> subject, you (will) come back to it again and again,  until it
> becomes a part of you.

What's the right word, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be "will". This is a conditional structure - 1st conditional. In conditional sentences, would is used in the 2nd conditional.

The rule for the 1st conditional is:

If + Present Tense    ,     will + inf / present tense / imperative

Examples:

If I have enough money, I will go to Japan. (present+will)

If the sum of the digits of a number is divisible by three, 
the number is divisible by three. (present+present)

If you see Mr Fox tonight, tell him I am ill. (present+imperative)

In your sentence(s), you are talking about (a) general fact(s). The part we need to look in terms of grammer is:

-if you talk to me about cars or soccer, I will yawn until my jaw snaps-